# How do I call this TypeScript function?

Tags: typescript, auth0

I am using a library that declares this function:"

```
import { Auth0JwtStrategy } from './strategy/auth0-jwt.strategy';
import { Auth0Service } from './auth0.service';
import { Auth0Options } from './auth0.interface';
export declare class Auth0Module {
    static register({ options, ...inject }: {
        options: Auth0Options;
        [name: string]: any;
    }): {
        module: typeof Auth0Module;
        providers: {
            provide: typeof Auth0JwtStrategy;
            useFactory: (auth0Service: Auth0Service) => Auth0JwtStrategy;
            inject: (typeof Auth0Service)[];
        }[];
    };
}
```

but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to call `Auth0Module.register`.

Auth0Options is declared as follows:

```
export interface Auth0Options {
    domain: string;
    clientId: string;
    clientSecret: string;
    audience?: string;
    namespace?: string;
}
```

I can't figure out how to formulate the parameters for that declaration.

Happy to provide more information if needed.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the weirder JS/TS things :-) Here's an untested solution, but might lead you on the right path:

```
Auth0Module.register(({ options, ...inject }) {
    return {
        module: ...,
        providers: ....,
    };
});
```

That `{ options, ...inject }` is a so-called destructured parameter and `{ options: Auth0Options; [name: string]: any; }` is the type of that.

More information and examples: https://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/use-destructuring-in-function-parameters/